# How to get webpage in the same state after reloading in jquery and html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, cgi

I have a webpage which is in some state currently, that is, some divs are shown and some are hidden. I am using cookies to post data to Python CGI scripts. So now, when I click a button, I want it to send data to the python cgi file, and so, I want the button reload the page, so that, due to reloading the cookie can be updated and thus, the updated cookie can be sent to the python-cgi file. (Also, I am using iframe to display the python-cgi file inside my html webpage).
Now, the methods such as `location.load()` doesn't work as it reloads the webpage into the initial state where all my divs were hidden but I want it to be in the same state as before reloading where some divs were shown and some were hidden.
How can I achieve that? Please help me with that! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The are two solutions I can think of to this problem:

1. JavaScript State-Saving Solution
2. Rewrite code as a REST API

### Solution 1: JavaScript State-Saving Solution

You can write a JavaScript function for when the button is clicked. And another one for when the page is loaded. Using the `localStorage` API, you can then save the current state of the page.

```js
function buttonClickedEvent() {
    const div1Visible = !document.querySelector('#div1').hidden || true;
    const div2Visible = !document.querySelector('#div2').hidden || true;
    const userInput = document.querySelector('#user-input').value || '';
    localStorage.setItem('page-state', JSON.stringify({
        div1Visible,
        div2Visible,
        userInput
    }));

    window.location.href = '/path/on/server';
}

function setupPage() {
    const state = localStorage.getItem('page-state');
    
    let stateObj;
    try {
        stateObj = JSON.parse(state);
    } catch (e) {
        return;
    }

    document.querySelector('#div1').hidden = !stateObj.div1Visible;
    document.querySelector('#div2').hidden = !stateObj.div2Visible;
    document.querySelector('#user-input').value = stateObj.userInput;
}
```

With the following HTML:

```html
<body onload='setupPage()'>
    <button onClick='buttonClickedEvent()'>
        Click Me
    </button>
</body>
```

### Solution 2: REST API (Ideal solution)

What I would recommend you do instead, is rewrite your server code such that it is a REST API, rather than using HTTP redirects. Then on the frontend, instead of changing the page, you use a library such as Axios to create HTTP requests:

```js
axios.get('/path/on/server', (response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) { // HTTP success
        // Code to run upon successful response
    }
});
```

---

Please let me know if there is anything you would like me to clarify.